# What is the most efficient way to search nested list in python?

Tags: python, list, search, nested-lists

Let's say I've a **nested loop** where I've listed result of a particular subject of students with name
like:

```
records = [[name, score]]
```

for example let's say we have list like these:

```
records = [['a', 67], ['b', 64], ['c', 63], ['d', 59]]
```

So here I want to print the maximum value with name?
I'm still noob in python so it will be great if you explain in easy way.
Thanks in advance <3

Comment: `max(records, key=lambda x: x[1])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.
One of which is by using the inbuilt function [max](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_max.asp) which finds the maximum value of its arguments. In this case an Array. Since we want to get the maximum value for the score, we need to get the integer from the array. We can do this by specifying a key function.

We can do this with an [anonymous function lambda](https://www.askpython.com/python/python-lambda-anonymous-function)
like this

```
records = [['a', 67], ['b', 64], ['c', 63], ['d', 59]]

print(max(records, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Or we can use a defined [function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) like this

```
records = [['a', 67], ['b', 64], ['c', 63], ['d', 59]]
def getScore(x):
    return x[1]
print(max(records,key=getScore))
```

There is a simpler or more understandable way of doing this. Using the library [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) and its function `item getter`

```
import operator

records = [['a', 67], ['b', 64], ['c', 63], ['d', 59]]
print(max(records,key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

Comment: And don't forget about `operator.itemgetter` :)

Comment: Huh, didn't know about that. Updating my answer to include it :D Thanks @revliscano

Comment: What do yoy mean? Marks?

Comment: I mean score,
forgot that I wrote score in main post sorry

Comment: `print(max(records, key=lambda x: x[1])[0])` like this?